# html css drop down menu help making it appear and dissappear

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Okay I have a menu  and wanting to group parts of it together. got that working, but struggling to make the drop down appear and disappear when hovering. also need to bring the drop menu to the front of a slide show when selected, unfortunately with a rep below 10 I cant post an image to show current screen image.

Got this far by looking at http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu and trying to relate it to my code, any help is much appreciated.

Can some one help point me in the right direction please. I can get the dropdown for panels to be permanently showing or permanently not showing, but need it to show when hovering over panels and not show when hovering over home.

```
<div id="menubar">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li>
<ul>
<li><a href="panels1.html">panels</a></li>
<li><a href="detectors.html">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="communicators.html">test 2</a></li>
</ul>
<li>
<li class="current"><a href="panels1.html">panels</a></li>
<li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>
<li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li> 
<li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--close menubar-->

ul#menu {
margin: 0;
display: inline;
list-style: none;}

ul#menu li {
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
margin: 2px 0 0 0;
display: inline-block;
background: #3d4f59;
position: relative;}

ul#menu li a {
float: left;
font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
height: 24px;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
padding: 6px 20px 0 20px;
background: #3d4f59;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;}

ul#menu li.current a {
color: #3d4f59;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
text-shadow: none;
position: relative;}

ul#menu li a:hover {
color: #3d4f59;
background: #FFF;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
text-shadow: none;}

ul#menu li ul {
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
background: #3d4f59;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
text-shadow: none;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;}

ul#menu li ul li {
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background: #3d4f59;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
text-shadow: none;
display: block;}
```

Comment: you need to add `display:none;` to the parts you want hidden, then add `display:block;` to its hover state

Comment: thats the problem I can't get the display to work so far the nearest i can get is for it to flicker, in reverse. ie have the block displayed and when I hover it dissapper.  but trun it other way round and it appears to do nothing, will hve another look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/xLqm7or3/1/

made changes to `Html markup` there was empty `<li>`

```
ul#menu li ul {
    display:none; /** added <- hide **/
}

ul#menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;  /** added <- on hover show **/
}
```

Comment: okay have the drop down menu appearing and disappearing when i hover but unable to select any of the options. so need to keep the drop down menu alive whilst I select the option. thanks its falling into place nicely.

Comment: I have to rub the cursor on panels then drag mouse down to select the menu option I want.

Comment: still having issues with this not being still to select. Solved my image over the top of the drop down menu by using z-index: 100; for the dropdown and the image it was behined set to z-index: 0;  so thats good.  Just have to get the drop down sio I can select the option without playing silly beggers with the mouse to select it.

Comment: interesting, your example now works like I would like, my site however does not. also my drop down is slightly to the right and yours is directly below panels. My site its still hit and miss with slecting the dropdown.........

Comment: thank you so much, I have found a line in my original css that is giving me issues, just need to see if removing causes any issues elsewhere, and track it back and fix with unique ids ul {
    margin: 2px 0 22px 30px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 100%}  I could not possibly have found this without knowing the code was working properly first. Thanks very much now to find out what that line did on what page.

Comment: your welcome :) add a class after ul `ul.xxx` if the styles are required

Comment: just noticed that current class carries through so I have highlighted options in the drop down list, so I tried a different class norm, ie normal rather than current, but that only change the first entry, so need to think of a smarter way but thats not a priority. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basical [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj02kbfn/) which will do the job.

```
/* Initially hide all second level ul's*/
ul#menu ul {
    display: none;
}

/* Show second level li's on hover*/
ul#menu li:hover+ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesnt appear to do anything at least inconjuction with the rest of my code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You html structure isn't correct. You want nested `ul` inside `li` elements for sub menus:

```css
ul#menu {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
ul#menu li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #3d4f59;
  position: relative;
}
ul#menu li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 24px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  padding: 6px 20px 0 20px;
  background: #3d4f59;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
ul#menu li.current a {
  color: #3d4f59;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  text-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: #3d4f59;
  background: #FFF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  text-shadow: none;
}
ul#menu li ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #3d4f59;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  text-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
ul#menu li ul li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #3d4f59;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3d4f59, #ccc);
  text-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="panels1.html">panels</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="detectors.html">test1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="communicators.html">test 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="help.html">Help</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--close menubar-->
```